# Can't access a path with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, steam

I am following [this guide](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2470784) to delete a Steam Cloud profile, and I have to clc a folder: `[Steam\userdata\95925904\381210\remote]`. Whenever I try to clc, I get an access denied error.

Here is a picture of the error - https://gyazo.com/cbab29f1daa2506b474683af42696ec1

I tried to open PowerShell as an administrator and it didn't help. Here is the error:

```
    Clear-Content : Access to the path "D:\ProgramFiles\other\Steam\userdata\95925904\381210\remote\ProfileSaves" is denied.
At line:1 char:4
+ clc <<<<  D:\ProgramFiles\other\Steam\userdata\95925904\381210\remote\*
+ CategoryInfo           :PremissionDenied: (D:\ProgramFiles...te\ProfileSaves:String) [Clear-Content], UnauthorizedAccessException 
+FullyQualifiedErrorId : ClearContentUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.ClearContentCommand
```

Comment: Please do not post images to error messages.  Please copy the error in plain text, and paste into your question.

Comment: This is an access/permissions thing.  For one, I'm surprised your "Program Files" directory doesn't have a space, but that's not necessarily bad or impossible.  *Are you certain Steam is closed*, when you try to run this?  It's possible it has an open lock on the file, to prevent access while running.

Answer (score 0):

Oké, have you tried to do it manual? Navigate to the folder, open the files (in notepad or something like that) and clear the content?

Just try to get the step from the guide done, if one way doesn't work try annother way that does the same. Try to understand what the step does.

clc just clears the content of the specified file(s). https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849853.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all instances of Steam and any Services it runs are stopped then try the clear

```
clc -path "D:\ProgramFiles\other\Steam\userdata\95925904\381210\remote\*"
```